# borrar espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de un campo

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una tabla con un campo llamado nombre, en ella tengo datos que al inicio le han puesto un espacio en blanco y al final otro espacio en blanco, necesito eliminar este espacio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el query debe ser algo así:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " 
set nombre = UPPER(TRIM(nombre)) nombre, REVERSE(UPPER(TRIM(nombre)))");
```

Pero actualmente no me funciona

Comment: Simplemente con `TRIM` debería funcionar, por ejemplo: `tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " 
set nombre = UPPER(TRIM(nombre))");` si es que son espacios en blanco realmente y no saltos de línea, tabulaciones, caracteres raros, etc. **Aviso:** Haz backup de la tabla antes de probar cualquier cosa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo simplemente con [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim):

> Returns the string str with all remstr prefixes or suffixes removed.
>   If none of the specifiers BOTH, LEADING, or TRAILING is given, BOTH is
>   assumed. remstr is optional and, if not specified, spaces are removed.
>
> ---
>
> Devuelve la cadena con todos los prefijos o sufijos remstr eliminados.
>   Si no se da ninguno de los especificadores BOTH, LEADING, o TRAILING,
>   se supone BOTH. remstr es opcional y, si no se especifica, se eliminan
>   los espacios.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
tep_db_query("update " . TABLE . " set nombre = UPPER(TRIM(nombre))");
```

#### Advertencia

Haz copia de seguridad antes de ejecutar modificaciones masivas.